# Programming Game of Life in C - Issue with bitwise operations

Tags: c, conways-game-of-life

I'm trying to program Conway's Game of Life in C but I am stumped as to how to store an ALIVE or DEAD cell.

The board is stored in an array of 32 unsigned longs (32x32 board) with each bit representing a cell (1 = alive, 0 = dead). I can't change this design.

So far, I have the code determining how many neighbors a particular cell has but I need to change its state based on the game's rules (a 1 may need to become either 0 or 1, a 0 may need to be either 1 or 0).

I assume I can use bitwise operations for this (|, &, ^) but I don't know how to isolate a particular bit in a row and store it as I iterate through the rest of the row and then store the new, re-calculate row as one unsigned long.

i.e. if 10011...0 needs to be 01101...1. How can I do this?

I realize the code will need additional for loops but I am just trying to wrap my head around this particular problem before proceeding.

Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
unsigned long columnMask;
int compass = 0;
int totAliveNeighbors = 0;
int iterator = 0;
int iterator2 = 0;

#define ARRAY_SIZE 32
#define NEIGHBORS 8

unsigned long grid[ARRAY_SIZE];
unsigned long copyGrid[ARRAY_SIZE];
unsigned long neighbors[NEIGHBORS];
unsigned long init32;
unsigned long holder = 0;

int main(void){
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("\n");

    /** Seeds the grid with random numbers **/
    for(iterator = 0; iterator < 32; iterator++){
        init32 = ((double)rand()/RAND_MAX)*0xFFFFFFFF;
        grid[iterator] = init32;
    }

    /** Displays the binary representation of the grid elements **/
    for(iterator = 0; iterator < 32; iterator++){  
        displayBinary(grid[iterator]);     
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");

    /** Calculate and sum neighbors for 'x' cell **/
    /** Will need to iterate through each column by shifting the mask **/
    /** Will need to iterate through each row **/
            iterator= 0; //example use
            neighbors[0] = north(iterator);
            neighbors[1] = south(iterator);
            neighbors[2] = east(iterator);
            neighbors[3] = west(iterator);
            neighbors[4] = northWest(iterator);
            neighbors[5] = northEast(iterator);
            neighbors[6] = southWest(iterator);
            neighbors[7] = SouthEast(iterator);

            columnMask = 0x80000000//need to shift by iterator value later on
            for(compass =0; compass < 8; compass++){
                totAliveNeighbors += ((columnMask & neighbors[compass])?1:0);
            }

}//end main

void displayBinary(unsigned long x){
    unsigned long MASK = 0x80000000;
    do {
        //printf("%c",(x & MASK)?'X':0x20);
        printf("%s", (x & MASK)?"1":"0");
    } while ((MASK >>=1)!=0);
}

unsigned long north(int rowNum){
    if(rowNum == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    else    
        return grid[rowNum-1];
}

unsigned long west(int rowNum){
    holder = grid[rowNum] >>1;
    return holder;
}

unsigned long east(int rowNum){
    holder = grid[rowNum] <<1;
    return holder;
}

unsigned long south(int rowNum){
    if(rowNum == 31)
        return 0;
    else    
        return grid[rowNum+1];
}

unsigned long northWest(int rowNum){
    if(rowNum == 0)
        return 0;
    else{
        holder = grid[rowNum-1] >>1;
        return holder;
    }
}

unsigned long northEast(int rowNum){
    if(rowNum == 0)
        return 0;
    else{
        holder = grid[rowNum-1] <<1;
        return holder;
    }    
}

unsigned long southWest(int rowNum){
    if(rowNum == 31)
        return 0;
    else{
        holder = grid[rowNum+1] >>1;
        return holder;
    }
}

unsigned long SouthEast(int rowNum){
    if(rowNum == 31)
        return 0;
    else{
        holder = grid[rowNum+1] <<1;
        return holder;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set a bit by ORing (`|`) with a value that has that bit set.

You can unset a bit by ANDing (`&`) with a value that has every bit set *except* that one.

You can turn a value that has one bit set into a value that has every bit except that one set with the NOT (`~`) operator.

You can tell if a bit is set by ANDing (`&`) with a value that only has that bit set, and seeing whether the result is true or false.

You can make a value with the nth bit (counting from the right, with the rightmost bit named the 0th bit) set by left-shifting (`<<`) the value `1` by *n* places.